# Putting the links and email in left/right corners

Tags: margins, templates, cv, resume

How can I place the link in the left and the email in the right corner of the resume

```
LinkedIn :  https://www.linkedin.com/in/abc-934894159/ email: XXX@gmail.com
```

I did this

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}  

% Default font is the helvetica postscript font
\usepackage{helvet}

% Increase text height
\textheight=700pt

\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND ADDRESS SECTION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\name{Adnan Farooq}

% Note that addresses can be used for other contact information:
% -phone numbers
% -email addresses
% -linked-in profile

\address{\\LinkedIn : https://www.linkedin.com/in/abc-934894159/ \hfill \hfill \hfill XXX@gmail.com \\}

% Uncomment to add a third address
%\address{Address 3 line 1\\Address 3 line 2\\Address 3 line 3}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{resume}
```

but its coming in center

[image]

Comment: Can you post more context regarding the code and the document class you are using? I am thinking your issue may be a function of the document class design but am not too sure.

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this class `res.cls` is very old and **should not used any more**.

Nevertheless, here is a dirty hack. Fake your "address" to be two "addresses":

```
\address{\\LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/abc-934894159/}
\address{\\XXX@gmail.com\\}
```

So with the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}  

% Default font is the helvetica postscript font
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% Increase text height
\textheight=700pt


\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND ADDRESS SECTION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\name{Adnan Farooq}

% Note that addresses can be used for other contact information:
% -phone numbers
% -email addresses
% -linked-in profile

\address{\\LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/abc-934894159/}
\address{\\XXX@gmail.com\\}

% Uncomment to add a third address
%\address{Address 3 line 1\\Address 3 line 2\\Address 3 line 3}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{resume}
\section{EDUCATION}
\textbf{University of ...} \hfill 2015--2019\\ 
BSc in ..., May 2019
\section{EMPLOYMENT} 
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]